# elasticsearch - add a constant mapping definition to a specific type in the mapping

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, mapping

I have a static mapping json that contains many entities. 
for instance

```
{
    "settings": {},
    "mappings": {
        "MyEntity": {
            "properties": {
                "date": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                },
                "tweet": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "user_id": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where "MyEntity" is an example of one of many entities.
What I want is that every time an entity has the value:

```
"name": { 
      "type": "string",
 },
```

this will be added:

```
"name": {
    "type": "string",
    "analyzer": "mm_name_analyzer",
    "fields": {
        "lc": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
        },
        "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to add it to each entity field that is defined as string.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Yes, use [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-templates). For example, take a look at the one from Logstash: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/v1.0.7/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json

Comment: Check out this. I hope you are tyring to achieve the multi field option for the name field. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html#_multi_fields

Comment: @AndreiStefan: Notice I am using static mapping. Can I use Dynamic template while using static mapping ? form your link "With dynamic_templates, you can take complete control over the mapping that is generated for newly detected fields"

Comment: You mean using both static mapping and dynamic for the same field?

Comment: Exactly, Every time I have a field "type":"string" it will add it the rest of the mapping. Edited the question for better explanation

Comment: The edit to the post doesn't match with the answer to my latest question. You cannot have both dynamic and static definitions for the same field. Meaning, you have a static mapping referring to `"name"` field. Having a dynamic definition for the same field doesn't make sense, you can easily update the static definition from the start and not rely on the dynamic definition. Specifically for a field named `name` you need something like this: `"match": "name",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string", .....`

Comment: I guess i did not explain myself well enough. I have a very long mapping file. In it there are many entities. in it there are many properties. some has type:string definition. I was looking for a way not to add the analyzer definition and the rest of the fields to each string property.

Comment: Now I understand. You basically want to write less code in an already static mapping. I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Thanks. exactly. I want to apply a template over a static maping file in order to make it shorter and also allow me to update the template in one place (when changed)

Answer (score -1):

Here replace indexName with the index of your purpose or give an index name pattern

You can apply mapping to "__default_" which will make sure that the mapping is applied to all the types under the indeices the dynamic mapping is applied to.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/nameTemplate -d '{
  "template": "indexName",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "name_field": {
            "match": "name",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "mm_name_analyzer",
              "fields": {
                "lc": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                },
                "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```